# CSS Content: Adding a style/class

Tags: css, html-lists, css-content

```
ol:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Article " counter(section) ". ";
 }
```

How do i add a class to content:?
if thats not possible a style will also do

Since you're inserting content, i want them to hide. If i remove the whole line it will not count

Currently it shows up like this:

```
Article 1: Terms of Condition

Article 1:
1.1 lorem ipsum
1.2 lorem ipsum
1.3 lorem ipsum
```

The 2nd "Article 1" should hide

Comment: Note that i dont want to add "terms of condition" just at the end of the line, because for other articles it would show up the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the `ol` element instead:

```
<ol class="... before-class">
```

Then style the `:before` pseudo-element using that:

```css
ol.before-class:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: visibility: hidden worked better for me, not sure why but it works now. Thanks James